# HTML5Boilerplate usage and restrictions

Tags: html5boilerplate

I'm thinking about building a Website and want to know the usage restrictions for Boilerplate.

I would like to use the latest version of HTML5 Boilerplate as the core/template of this project but can't find info on what I can and can't do.

Is it legal to use for commercial purposes?

Answer (score 0):

As per the `LICENSE.MD` file in the root of the downloadable archive:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the
>   "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including
>   without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish,
>   distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to
>   permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to
>   the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be
>   included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

So yes, you can pretty much do anything with it what you want.